# External connections and paging. Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have an application with "spring boot" and I need to connect to a new Mysql database to read a table. Everything works correctly, I do not know if it is the best way to do it and how I can do a pagination.

// MY Connection

```
package com.xxx.xxx.config;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

public class DatabaseAsteriskConfiguration {

private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
private static HikariDataSource ds;

static {
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx/db");
    config.setUsername("xxxx");
    config.setPassword("xxx");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
}

public DatabaseAsteriskConfiguration() {
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return ds.getConnection();
}
}
```

// My REPOSITORY

```
package com.xxxx.xxxx.asterisk;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.abalia.elser2.config.DatabaseAsteriskConfiguration;

@Repository
public class AsteriskRepository {

Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
List<AsteriskDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();

public List<AsteriskDTO> loadAll(String inicio, String fin) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DatabaseAsteriskConfiguration.getConnection();

        // STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE calldate >= '" + inicio + "' and calldate <= '" + fin + "'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        // STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while (rs.next()) {
            AsteriskDTO dto = new AsteriskDTO();
            dto.setSrc(rs.getString("src"));
            dto.setDst(rs.getString("dst"));
            dto.setDuration(rs.getInt("duration"));
            dto.setCalldate(rs.getTimestamp("calldate"));

            // Display values
            System.out.println("src: " + dto.getSrc() + "calldate: " + dto.getCalldate());
            list.add(dto);
        }
        // STEP 6: Clean-up environment
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        return list;
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        // Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // finally block used to close resources
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        } // nothing we can do
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } // end finally try
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

Someone can help me how is the best way to connect to BBDD that are not the main application and interecturar with them in the best way, and how to do the paging.